# Dynamic multiple ordered nested sum

Tags: summation

I have a function f[r,n] dependening on two tables $r=\{r_1,...,r_j\},n=\{n_1,...,n_j\}$ which have the same variable size $j$. For given $j$ and given $R$ I want to sum f[r,n] over the range $0< n_1 \leq r_1 < n_2 \leq r_2 < \dots < n_j \leq r_j  \leq R$. What is the best way to do this in mathematica?

I saw that there are related questions, but in those cases it seems that the summation variables are usually not ordered, i.e. dependend on eachother.

Edit: Here an example for the case j=2. The f here is not the real f but it shows just an example of a function depending on two tables. I want the sum on the bottom be dynamical and use the j, which is now hardcoded in the Sum.

```
f[r_, n_] := Product[r[[i]]*n[[i]], {i, 1, Length[r]}];  

R = 10;  
j = 2;  
Sum[f[{r1, r2}, {n1, n2}], {r2, 1, R}, {n2, 1, r2}, {r1, 1,n2-1}, {n1, 1, r1}]
```

Comment: Please provide `f[r, n]` and typical lists of `r` and `n`.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it good enough. f is a function which gets to tables as parameter (and it should not matter how f looks like for the question). Given j (the length of the tables) and R i want to take a sum over all possible lists r,n of length j, which have entries satisfying the inequality I wrote.

Comment: @henrik691 It's unnecessarily hard to try to solve your general problem abstractly, without a practical example. It's much more likely that people will expend effort to help you if you provide everything they need to play with your problem. Your question will attract less attention if potential respondents also have to create their own sample lists and data and function to play around with. If the problem were so simple that somebody could solve it just from an abstract description, then you'd probably have solved it already yourself using the documentation :-)

Comment: Ok I edited the original post with an example. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing some related question ([Nested ordered summation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172518/nested-ordered-summation?rq=1)) I finally found an answer (after some adaptation) which does exactly what I wanted. In case someone else will read my question in the future: here is a solution:

```
j = 3;
R = 5;

Sum[f[Table[r[l], {l, 1, j}], Table[n[l], {l, 1, j}]], 
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
   Reverse[Flatten[
     Table[{{n[i], 1, r[i]}, {r[i], 1, 
        If[i == j, R, n[i + 1] - 1]}}, {i, 1, j}], 1]]]]
```

Comment: Please add a link to the useful answer(s). Thanks.

Comment: @Syed Ok I edited the post and included the link I used.